# Open files with values stored in cells

Tags: excel, vba

Okay the title is a little ambiguous but what I'm trying to do is the following:
I have a column of file names and I want to open them all using vba.  I'm assuming it would be something like what I have below but I'm missing something. The number of files can change so I can't use a definite range.

```
For each cl in workbookC.worksheets("sheet1").range("A"). If cl.value <> "" then. Open (filename="cl.value"). End if. Next cl
```

Comment: To be sure, the files you are opening are excel files?  Do you really want to just open them all?  Or do you want to open them, do something, then close them?

Comment: @mr.Reband yes they are excel files; I would ideally like to open them two at a time and close them but I get a message each time the files open saying there are links to other files in them and I don't want the macro to keep stopping so I'd rather open all the files at once

Comment: For suppressing the warning, see this article:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14908372/how-to-suppress-update-links-warning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below should work.  Note that I would suggest not only making sure that the cell is not blank but also checking if the file exists using a FileSystemObject before attempting to opening.

```
Dim sourceWorksheet
Set sourceWorksheet = workbookC.Worksheets("sheet1")

Dim row
For row = 1 To 10       'rows containing filenames
    If sourceWorksheet.Cells(row, 1).Value <> "" Then
        Dim xlwb
        Set xlwb = Workbooks.Open(sourceWorksheet.Cells(row, 1).Value)
            'do stuff
        xlwb.Close
    End If
Next
```