# VBA excel Opening Documents with External Links

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink, break

I am trying to note down what documents have external links in them.

I have written a macro that opens and closes all documents in a folder. I wait for the message to pop up saying this documents has links. I then press ctrl + break to break to code and check what document it is, I then write down the name of the document and press F5 to continue. This works but it is slow and tedious when i have 1000s of documents to check and I have to pay attention to it.

Anyone know another way of checking documents for external links so I don't have to use the popup? I have tried using On Error Go to etc but Excel doesn't see the update links message as a error.

If anyone knows of any other ways that would be much appreciated.

Comment: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/784326-vba-list-all-external-links-together-cells-containing-links.html

Comment: Have a look at [Workbook.LinkSources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.linksources?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm199109)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

Comment: try `Application.DisplayAlerts` as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14908372/how-to-suppress-update-links-warning

Comment: @chrisneilsen thanks for that link. It looks like its exactly what I want but I can't get any results. I have a workbook open with a link to another workbook and test the code and it returns nothing.