# I actually want Excel links to be updated when I open another Excel file with VBA, however, I can only find how to suppress the question

Tags: excel, vba

I'd be very surprised if this isn't a duplicate, however, I can't find anything that matches what I want to do.

I'm opening up a workbook with multiple external links programatically. I don't want to be told about the links (Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False), I just want it to update them. There's lots about suppressing warnings: [How to suppress Update Links warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14908372/how-to-suppress-update-links-warning), as an example, there's a few about updating link paths, but I can't quite find anything on just straight up, "Yes open the file and update the data in the links", AKA the same as hitting "Update" when opening the workbook.

I'm pretty sure it's a single line method, something like

Answer (score 0):

And as I was typing the question, it went click, and I checked the documentation. It was there! application.open updatelinks = true https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.open

UpdateLinks = true should do it. Going to test it now